# Storage:: check creation file. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file

My code is here:

```
Storage::disk(‘local’)->put($name,$information);
```

I want to check if my file created and echo a message.
If it will be created I want to echo “You created”.
If it not I want to echo “Your file didn’t create".
How can do it this?

Comment: Did you already try something? Did you research?

Comment: @Perazim. No.I don’t know how to approach it.

Comment: `put` should throw an exception if it can't create the file. You can try/catch for that.

Comment: Yes, i did it.This was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [`Storage::exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#retrieving-files):

```
$exists = Storage::disk('s3')->exists('file.jpg'); // true/false
```

or [`file_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php):

```
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

Comment: I don’t want to check if it exists my file, but if it will be created

Comment: I'm not following what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: My file sometimes cannot be created and i want to inform me my project with message if this happen.

Comment: @NickPeropoulos and the above too will do exactly that. They'll tell you if the file exists (i.e. has been created).

Comment: @NickPeropoulos If it wasn't created, it doesn't exist, right?

Comment: Yes.I adapted the code and I take the solution. Thanks @Script47